# Continuous time markov chain for automobile shop

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given customers arrive at an automobile shop in a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1 = 2$ per hour. If there are $\geq 3$ customers, the owner would turn away the arriving customers. These customers then leave. Finally, the times to complete service for customers are independent exponential random variables with mean $1$ per hour.

(a) Find the average number of customers in the shop.

(b) When the shop is full ($3$ customers), find the probability of at least one automobile completes the service before the next one arrives.

(c) Find the fraction of customers turned away.

**My attempt** I was able to construct the rate transition matrix $Q$ as $$Q =\pmatrix{-2 & 2 &  0 &  0 \\ 1 & -3 &  2 &  0 & \\ 0 &  1 &  -3 &  2 & \\ 0 &  0 &  1 &  -1}$$

(the 1st column/1st row = 0 cars in the shop, 2nd column/2nd row = 1 car in the shop, etc. and the 4th column = $\geq 3$ cars in the shop)

But I could not see how to use this transition matrix Q to solve (b), so could anyone please help with this part?

For part (c), I think this is just $1 - P(\text{0 car is finished before the next car arrives}) = 1 - \frac{1}{2+1} = \frac{2}{3}$. Is this correct though?

For part (d), I need to find $P_3$ for the equation $PQ = 0$ with $\sum_{i=0}^{3}  P_i = 1$. My answer is $\frac{8}{15}$.

**My question:** Could anyone please help me with part (a)? Also, please let me know if I got the other two parts incorrectly. Really appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Could anyone please give this problem a try? I'm just dumb:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z(t)$ be the number of customers in the system at time $t$, then $\{Z(t):t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ is a continuous-time Markov chain on state space $S:=\{0,1,2,3\}$ with generator matrix $Q$ as written in the question. Since $\{Z(t)\}$ is irreducible on a finite state space, it has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$. $\{Z(t)\}$ is a birth-death process, so $\pi$ satisfies the detailed balance equations
\begin{align}
\pi_0\lambda &= \pi_1\mu\\
\pi_1\lambda &= \pi_2\mu\\
\pi_2\lambda &= \pi_3\mu\\
\end{align}
Let $\rho=\frac\lambda\mu(=2)$, then we have $\pi_1=\rho\pi_0$, $\pi_2=\rho^2\pi_0$, and $\pi_3=\rho^3\pi_0$. It follows from $\sum_{i\in S}\pi_i=1$ that 
$$\pi_0(1+2+4+8) = 1$$ and hence $$\pi = \left(\frac1{15},\frac2{15},\frac4{15},\frac8{15}\right). $$

For $(a)$, the limiting mean number of customers in the shop is given by
$$L = \sum_{i\in S}i\pi_i = 1\cdot\frac2{15}+2\cdot\frac4{15}+3\cdot\frac8{15}= \frac{34}{15}.$$

For $(b)$, let $S$ be the number of services completed before the next arrival, then 
$$\mathbb P(S\geqslant 1)=1-\mathbb P(S=0) = 1 - \frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}= 1 - \frac2{2+1} = \frac13. $$

For $(c)$, the fraction of customers turned away is the fraction of customers that arrive when the shop is full: $\pi_3 = \frac8{15}$.

I didn't see a part $(d)$, but indeed $\pi Q=0$ and $\pi_3=\frac8{15}$, as that part seems to be asking.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Great answer for part (a), although I wonder if there is a difference between limiting mean and the (normal) average?

Comment: For any time $T>0$, the average number of customers in the system up to time $T$ is $$\frac1T\int_0^T Z(t)\,\mathsf dt, $$ which is not feasible to compute. However, if there is a limiting distribution $\pi$ with mean $m$, then $$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac1T\int_0^T Z(t)\,\mathsf dt = m.$$

Comment: I see now. Could you also give this problem a try: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950233/rate-transition-matrix-of-a-machine

Comment: I could. But I did my homework for a course at this level five years ago and eventually tire of solving such problems ;)

Comment: Of course, that your demand is so pressing smells like systematic externalization of your homework, which is no incentive to answer your questions. On the contrary, one could imagine that you study in depth the answer you received *here* to see if you cannot adapt it *there*... Note that we still do not know what in the rather direct (but technically competent) answer here was escaping you when you posted the question, although this kind of information would be crucial to engage in an effective learning process.

Comment: @Did: I thought I was clear enough when I posted the question. Basically, for part (b), I did not think of the question as "calculating the expected value," and did not know that we can calculate expected value using the limiting probabilities (the $\pi_{i}$s) In addition, I thought the number of automobiles at any particular point could be some non-integer numbers (completely off with that thought). I'm sorry for creating a false impression to you, but I'm reviewing for my incoming qual exam. Hope this helps.